# What is this round board game on a turn table?

Tags: identify-this-game

[image]The board has 32 sections with 4 peg holes in each section. There are 4 numbered pegs each a different color.  There are 4 die with numbers 1 through 6 following the same colors as the pegs.  It is mounted on a turn table.  Does anyone know what game this is?

Comment: note: this question has also been asked [on Board Game Geek](https://www.boardgamegeek.com/thread/2294540/identifying-board-game-pictures-me-too)

Answer (score 5):

It looks like a home made tabletop version of Horse Racing.
https://www.instructables.com/id/Horse-Racing-Game/

You roll the dice and move the horse along the number that's on its die.  The first to cross the finish line wins.